# two Ubuntu server installs on a single computer

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, grub2

I'm setting up a system that is going to be used for two primary purposes.
A - a system to learn more about linux, virtualization, cloud tech, etc.
B - a system dedicated to running eve-ng for building network simulations

From what I can tell reading the EVE docs, when you install it on bare metal, it sort of "takes over" the system, so I would rather leave it alone and not being doing other things on it.

So I've decided to have two independent installs of Ubuntu server.
The install for task A above will have two drives (SSD primary boot drive, and a large /home drive.)  Considering I'm using it to educate myself, it's possible I will end up having to re-install and start over.
The install for task B above will have a pair of 2T HDs setup in RAID1 as I expect to use the eve system heavily and don't want to lose a ton of simulated networks, etc due to disk failure.
I should add, that ideally these to partitions/installs would use the same grub partition so that I can remotely modify which one will boot on the next system boot, as I would prefer to operate the machine headless if at all possible.

At this point, I've got the machine loaded up for task A.
When I go to re-run the Ubuntu server installer, and if I select the RAID logical volume to install to, it also wants to touch the SSD.  What I can't tell is whether this is just to update the grub install on that drive, or if it is planning to use that partition for something else with the second install.

So I pulled the SSD and the other HD out and installed Ubuntu server like that.
But now I've got two grub partitions.  I used grub customizer and modified the grub setup for install A.  And if I have a monitor attached and ensure I hit that one via the UEFI boot menu, then I can select whichever one I want.  As well as I can modify the grub setup so that when I reboot it will boot into install B.  But at this point, I have no way to switch it back.

So my questions are.

#1 - What is the server install wanting to do to the SSD during installation of the second copy when I have only pointed it at the RAID logical volume?  Is the installer smart enough to see the existing grub partition and only use that?  I don't think that is what it was doing as there was a grub partition being setup in addition to the primary volume and the SSD listed.

#2 - How can you get the installer on 18.04 to not install grub?  I was thinking that if I didn't install a second grub partition, then I could later point the second install at the single grub partition and be able to modify it from either system.  This would give me the ability to switch back and forth remotely.

#3 - Is there a better way to do what I am attempting?  Am I over-complicating the situation?

#4 - Can I launch subiquity from the first installation to setup the second?  If so, is there a document that outlines that process?

Any other suggestions?

Comment: Why not use VMware on the bare metal and set up two virtual servers? Then you could run both at the same time if you wanted or shut one down for your benchmarking.

Comment: FYI:   I don't try and prevent grub installs (I used to use tricks to force the installer to put it somewhere that doesn't matter), but now let it destroy whatever it wants (it's only going to overwrite 512 bytes of disk!) and just restore that sector (512 bytes) later... It's actually faster (easier too as less error prone in my experience). Ubuntu has tutorials, eg. https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-server#1-overview  (the ISO used to install can control the best tutorial geared for you; `subiquity` tends to update itself so its less variable than *di* installer)

Comment: Your first install won't have `subiquity` installed (it's on installation media which doesn't get installed on the end system), so you're asking about modifying your first install so you can use it to install another system?  That seems counter-productive to me...  *you could always have the ISO on your disk & modify `grub` to have it run from the from the first disk/partition, but again why not use media twice?*

Comment: Why not use vmware?  Because the EVE-NG system will be running KVM hosting various networking equipment VMs, and nested virtualization really bogs down, especially since some of the networking device VMs are themselves running VMs....

Comment: I think I've figured out a solution.  I just reinstalled EVE-NG, and then booted back into the first Ubuntu installation.  From that one I've deleted the second GRUB partition, so the system would only have the single one for UEFI to find/boot.   Any time I power on the system it will boot into that first Ubuntu.  I can then select to boot into EVE from Ubuntu, just can't boot directly into it.  I'm testing that now.

Comment: I was asking about launching subiquity from the first installation so that I could flag it not to install grub, as there is an option for that, just no way to set it from the USB install media.